# how to pass columname as params with pandas read_sql_query function

Tags: python, pandas, mariadb

I am writing a sql query where I want to pass a WHERE condition with parameters in pandas.read_sql_query.
It works fine for the value but I encounters problems with the variable.
My workaround is a concated string which I pass to pandas, but I don't like to see my code so.
I already figured out, that the column name of the table is written wrong. It is e.g. 'colname' instead of colname.

I wrote the sql as string:

```
command=("SELECT * FROM review r "
                     "WHERE 1=1  " 
                     "AND "+selected_var+"= "+selected_val
                     )
```

And then i passed it to pandas

```
self.reviews = pd.read_sql_query(command, con = self.cnxn)
```

But I would like to include it without workaround.

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

self.reviews = pd.read_sql_query("""
   SELECT *
   FROM review r
   WHERE 1=1
      AND  %(sel_var)s  = %(sel_val)s;
 """, con = self.cnxn, params = {'sel_var': selected_var,
                                 'sel_val': selected_val
  })
```

I expect that the query shows results without writing everything as command string.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I do not want to use the command workaround, to set up an extra string.
But i cannot give the name of column by pd.read_sql_query(params). If I do so, I do not receive any result row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about string formatting?

```
input_params = {'sel_var': selected_var,
                'sel_val': selected_val}

self.reviews = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM review r WHERE 1=1 
                                     AND {sel_var}={sel_val};""".format(**input_params), 
                                 con = self.cnxn)
```

Comment: By using that snipped the problem is reversed.
Now the var information (column) is handled correctly by the val information is handled as column as well. the \' are missing. I cannot select chars in the WHERE condition
if I apply a mixture of .format and pd.read_sql_query(params) it works, but is not optimal.

Comment: If your `selected_val` is a char, you need to enclose it like this in the query `AND {sel_var}='{sel_val}'`.

Comment: well that is the solution. Thank you @Julia